# Are there electrically controlled precision rheostats that are not solid state

Tags: resistors, resistor-ladder

I need precision variable resistors for a programmable analog computer that I'm trying to construct.

An analog computer requires variable resistors that can be set with precision.

I don't want to use digital components because the have discrete steps and are not pure resistors (have capacitance)

My first thought was to connect a dc motor via reduction gears to a precision rheostat -- wire that to a digital ohm meter and build a control circuit that dials the rheostat to the desired value.

Are there off the shelf components that I can buy or will I have to construct my own.

Notes:

1. On using a MOSFET as a variable resistor -- based on [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72263/mosfet-as-a-voltage-controlled-resistor), it looks like it will be difficult to deal with the nonlinear behavior -- plus the ohomic range seems narrow.
2. I looked at digitally controlled rheostats but they have several limitations including the fact that they are active solid-state components and that they have discreet steps (typically 256 and 1024 on the high end.

Comment: Is solid state really not an option? There are analog solid state solutions.

Comment: Make up your mind -- in one paragraph, you say you don't want anything with discrete steps, but in another, you say you'll use a digital ohmmeter. How exactly do you intend to specify the desired value of the resistance?

Comment: A MOSFET is basically a voltage controlled resistor. All you need to do know is combat the odd curve.

Comment: @DaveTweed fair point -- but I reckon that a digital ohm meter uses pretty precision measurement techniques? or am I missing something ? thanks

Comment: Sounds to me that this is just a dream project from someone who hasn't tried to do the math and found out _what_ kind of precision and accuracy you need.

Comment: @Bradman175, thanks for the comment ... so I can use a MOSFET as a precision resistor?

Comment: you are correct in that this is fun project -- if I wanted to be practical I would just solve the state space equations digitally using matlab

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, I looked at digitally controlled resistors but they seem to be composed of active components and come in discreet steps -- typically 256 and sometimes 1024

Comment: That's far better than any motorized control.

Comment: "Solid state" doesn't mean "digital".

Comment: @pipe - apparently someone has built such a product (must've been dreaming). I must admit I was a bit annoyed at your snide comment. I don't know what your flair is as an electrical engineer - I studied at EE at a top 5 school 20 years ago and did ok, didn't work in EE professionally. Rather than snide remarks it is beneficial to be helpful and if you cannot - save the white space on the web page. On mathematics - that's how I put bread on my table - want to try fencing mathematically - I'm not the one who'll end up bleeding. So have some respect -- I'm sure your momma tried to teach you that

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- I mean really I think I know as much -- do you have something that is helpful or are you just having a bad day -- I've thought my application through and I'm asking for help. Can you help me?

Comment: A JFET and an op amp.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- thanks let me look at that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- the resistors are a very important part of an analog computer -- I quickly scanned a couple of papers and it seems that signal distortion is an issue. Not sure if you still think I should continue with that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed - [this motorized potentiometer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10976). Note that it has two separate resistive tracks. Or had you not realized that you have to disconnect a resistor from its' circuit to measure it?